# Fast vector/sparse-matrix/vector multiplication

Tags: python, performance, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to perform a "sparse outer product" of two 1-dimensional arrays x and y, subject to a sparse "template matrix" T. For example, I want to compute something like

```
x= np.array([1,2,3,4])
y= np.array([5,6,7])
T=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,1,0]])
np.multiply(T,np.outer(x,y))
```

which produces

```
array([[ 5,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0, 14],
   [15, 18,  0],
   [ 0, 24,  0]])
```

The challenge is to make this fast. The basic computational problem with this naive code is that it performs many unnecessary multiplications in the outer product.  One should only have to perform multiplications where the template is nonzero.

I have tried using SciPy sparse methods, for example:

```
T_lil=lil_matrix(T)
T_csr=T_lil.tocsr()
diags(x).dot(T_csr.dot(diags(y)))
```

This theoretically avoids unnecessary multiplications by applying T first to y, then applying x to the result.  It gains a speed advantage for large sizes but is so slow for smaller sizes that I know it can't be optimal.

I also tried things like

```
x_column=np.array([x]).T
(T_csr.multiply(x_column)).multiply(y)
```

which (after applying .toarray()) gives the same answer, but this is absurdly clunky and again can't be optimal.

I don't think it would help to convert x and y to a sparse encoding, because they are generally NOT sparse in my application.

Can anybody help?  For my application, T might have 10^4 rows and 10^5 columns. I don't at all mind digging into the guts of the csr (or csc or coo or dok) encoding, but I expect somebody knows a better answer than I can think of.

Comment: "It gains a speed advantage for large sizes but is so slow for smaller sizes that I know it can't be optimal." - how small are we talking? There's a limit to how sparse a small matrix can be without being a zero matrix. Your small matrices may not be sparse enough for any sparsity-based optimizations to pay off.

Comment: In general, how sparse is `T` expected to be?

Comment: And is `T` guaranteed to be a zero-one matrix?

Comment: If you were working in C or C++, this kind of analysis may make sense.  But in `numpy` this focus on the number of multiplications is misplaced.  Multiplying two numbers, even when one is 0, isn't that expensive.  Trying to take advantage of the sparsity of `T` requires a lot of extra indexing, which ends up being as expensive.  With a simple `dot`, I've found that a sparse matrix needs to have a sparsity less than 10% to gain any speed advantage over its dense equivalent (that's without any dense to sparse conversion in timing).

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,i,j->ij',T,x,y)` is a bit faster than your first computation.  `x[:,None]*T*y[None,:]` is another dense expression.

Comment: The outer product is completely memory bandwidth limited. How sparse is T? If T is sparse enough, which format do you expect at the end (conversion between formats is also slow). And maybe more important: What do you want to do next with the result? If there are some reductions (sum) involved, the whole operation can be done a lot faster than the calculation you asked for alone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something simple you could do with a COO-format `T` matrix. Use advanced indexing to multiply `T.data` by the correct elements of `x` and `y`:

```
result = coo_matrix((T.data * x[T.row] * y[T.col], (T.row.copy(), T.col.copy())),
                    shape=T.shape)
```

The `copy` calls avoid a few cases where modifying one of `T` or `result` might affect the other. You can remove them if you're sure you won't modify your matrices.

Also, be aware that this `result` might have explicit zeros, particularly if `x` or `y` have any zeros.